# Compiler time code blocks

Tags: go

Is it possible to detect for example OS name at compiler time and compiler specified code block like:

```
version(windows)
{
}

version(linux)
{
}
```

Comment: And though you should prefer build constraints, there are also the `runtime.GOOS` and `runtime.GOARCH` constants: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#pkg-constants

Answer (score 6):

Go resolves this automatically in build-time. All you need to place the code in corresponding files:

- `file_linux.go` - code for linux version
- `file_windows.go` - code for windows version.

> If a file's name, after stripping the extension and a possible `_test` suffix, matches any of the following patterns:
>
> *_GOOS
>
> *_GOARCH
>
> *_GOOS_GOARCH 
>   (example: `source_windows_amd64.go`)
>
> where GOOS and GOARCH represent any known operating system and architecture values
>   respectively, then the file is considered to have an implicit build
>   constraint requiring those terms (in addition to any explicit
>   constraints in the file).
>
> Naming a file `dns_windows.go` will cause it to be included only when
>   building the package for Windows; similarly, `math_386.s` will be
>   included only when building the package for 32-bit x86.

https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints